# 'ng' is not recognized - Running an Angular app via electron

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I know this question has been asked already, but the reply was not helpful to me.

I try to run an Angular app in electron by typing in Visual Studio code integrated terminal the following command:
npm start

The error I get is:
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

The log file looks as following:

[image]

Now:

1. I have node installed:

Running command node -v gives me - v8.9.4

2. I have angular Cli inatalled.
   Running the command npm list @angular/cli
   gives me: `-- @angular/cli@6.0.3
3. I went to the folder of Environment Variable
   The PATH variable looks as following:

C:\users\dim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin

What else can I do in order to solve the issue?

Comment: npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PATH variable should not contain `C:\users\dim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin` but `C:\users\dim\AppData\Roaming\npm`.

Here are the `.cmd` files that are created when you install libraries globally :

```
npm i -g @angular/cli@latest
```